# handling missed column without editing query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have question in mysql server

```
table: emp 
id   |     name   |    sal      | deptno | loc     |   referby
 1   |      abc   |     100     |10      | hyd     |    xyz
 2   |      mnc   |     200     |20      |chen     |    pqr   

table : emp1
id   |     name   |    sal      | deptno | loc     
 3   |      xyz   |     300     |10      | hyd     

table : emp2
id   |     name   |    deptno   | loc     
 4   |      opq   |     20      | hyd     
 5   |      mnc   |     40      |chen
```

I tried like below query

```
insert into empfinal
(
select  id  , name ,sal deptno  ,loc ,referby  from emp
union all
select  id  , name ,sal deptno  ,loc ,'NA' as referby  from emp1
union all
select  id  , name ,'NA' as sal, deptno  ,loc ,'NA' as referby  from emp2
)
```

but is not work in mysql server  and here emp and emp1 and emp2 table may be some time
delete few columns and some time may be add few column for above table but 
finaly  structure never change to compare with
empfinal table. I mean above table  must  have upto empfinal table  columns only .some time  3 columns
and some time 4 columns  and some time  all 6 columns avilble  in emp or emp1 or emp2 table.

I want load above there tables related data into empfinal table  and data look like below

```
table: empfinal 
id   |     name   |    sal      | deptno | loc     |   referby
 1   |      abc   |     100     |10      | hyd     |    xyz
 2   |      mnc   |     200     |20      |chen     |    pqr 
 3   |      xyz   |     300     |10      | NA      |     NA
 4   |      opq   |      NA     | 20     | hyd     |     NA 
 5   |      mnc   |      NA     | 40     | chen    |     NA
```

I do not want keep editing the query to account for possible missing columns. 
can youe please tell me query how to ahcive this task in mysql server.

Comment: Why do you have so many tables? If you want to join multiple tables, you have to use union all only. May be you can try redesigning your table structure if applicable.

Comment: Redesign tables option  did not provide permission   to the developers and  we need to resolve based on this situation.as per there business purpose they used required columns  corresponding tables only used  based day(daily) wise transaction.is it possible or not if column is there then retrive corresponding data othere wise keep 'NA' can you please tell me query to achieve this task

Answer (score 0):

In the data shown, the id seems to have unique values and hence can be primary key.

If possible, try to redesign your DB tables to have all values in a single table as table 'emp' with following fields.

```
id   |     name   |    sal      | deptno | loc     |   referby
```

It is OK if some fields have null values. You can use functions like `NVL(SAL,'NA')` to replace empty values from a table with 'NA'

If not, then probably you have no other option but to only use a union query.

Comment: Redesign tables option  did not provide permission   to the developers and  we need to resolve based on this situation.as per there business purpose they used required columns  corresponding tables only used  based day(daily) wise transaction.is it possible or not if column is there then retrive corresponding data othere wise keep 'NA' can you please tell me query to achieve this task

Comment: @srinivasa: Are you getting any error? maybe using 'NA' in emp3 table will cause issues. Because salary seems to be a numeric column and 'NA' is text value.

Comment: all columns datatype  is varchar only.here finely we need to fix this issue using dynamic missed columns query  from emp,emp1,emp2 tables

Comment: @srinivasa: I doubt if there is another mechanism available. AFAIK, the type of query you already use is the only way to solve this issue.

Comment: if we do above logic query every time we need to change query any columns delete/added above there tables.for that purpose I want dynamic query to handle this issue. thanks!